# how to set automatic height on div for mobile but fixed desktop

Tags: css, responsive-design, height

I have a site that is metro styled tiles.  On the desktop all tiles are fixed in width. I would like some of the divs to be based on content height when it goes to mobile though.

If I set height to auto, the div dissappears.

my site is http://p2p.rudtek.com/you/.  The photo one top on desktop is a wide tile and the content below is in a tall tile.

```
.tile.tall {
    width: 488px;
    height: 737px;
}

.tile-post.wide {
    width: 737px;
    height: 488px;
       color: #FFFFFF;
       font-size: 4em;
}
```

when it goes to mobile I want them to be full width and auto height.

I tried this:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 480px) {
  .tile-post.wide {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    padding-bottom:0;
  }
  .tile-post.tall {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
  }
}
```

the width is fine, but when I use auto they don't show up, so I have to put a height.  Is there any way to make them auto height based on content?

Comment: Can you share more of your code? My guess is that something else is overriding your height settings.

Comment: Looking at your site, you're using absolute positioning. No way to auto-height without stacking frames

Comment: @bertrand  The live site is using absolute and auto height  page2pro.com

Comment: Might seems a silly question but : are you sure the text is inside the div and not in another container ? no text = no height unless hard set.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add this to your mobile css:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 480px) {
   .tile-post > :first-child
   {
      position:relative;
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help.  It didn't seemed to work.  My live site is using absolute on mobile and auto height is being respected.